# Why source port on DatagramChannel change in middle of connection?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have Android client which connect to server. For some reason, the source port of android change while the connection still active.

```
channel = DatagramChannel.open();
if (!protect(channel.socket())) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the channel");
}
channel.connect(server);
while (true) {
    //Send something
}
```

While it keep sending data, suddenly the source port change. Is there any reason why that is happening ? If so, is there a way to prevent it ?

Regards

Adrian

Edit:

[image]

[image]

It seem the port keep changing and server cannot reach the original port.

Comment: Evidence? Code? Question?